# How to fix GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException when using a Pool?

Tags: php, guzzle

[The docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests) say I can create a pool and any failed requests should call the "rejected" method, but instead I'm getting `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException`. Here's my code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => ServerConfig::Json('file_server'),
]);

$requests = function() use ($client, $delete_time) {
    foreach($this->pcs_master->pcs as $id => $pcs) {
        $paths = $pcs->database->SelectSimpleArray('wopi_doc', 'wd_filepath', ['wd_deleted_at IS NOT NULL', 'wd_deleted_at < ?' => $delete_time]);

        if ($paths) {
            foreach (array_chunk($paths, self::WOPI_SOFT_DELETE_CHUNK_SIZE) as $chunk) {
                yield $client->delete('/', [
                    'body' => json_encode(['paths' => $files]),
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
};

$pool = new GuzzleHttp\Pool($client, $requests(), [
    'concurrency' => self::WOPI_SOFT_DELETE_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS,
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
        dump('fulfilled', $response, $index);
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
        dump('rejected', $reason, $index);
    },
]);

$pool->promise()->wait();
```

Here's the exception:

```
TYPE: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException
MESSAGE: Server error: 500
FILE: /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(68)
=== TRACE ===
#0 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(199): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(152): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
#2 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(60): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
#3 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(240): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run(true)
#4 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(217): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn()
#5 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(261): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#6 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(219): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList()
#7 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#8 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(129): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait()
#9 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(87): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('delete', '/', Array)
#10 /path/to/my/project/class/crondaemon.php(5057): GuzzleHttp\Client->__call('delete', Array)
#11 /path/to/my/project/class/crondaemon.php(5057): GuzzleHttp\Client->delete('/', Array)
#12 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Pool.php(55): CronDaemon::{closure}()
#13 [internal function]: GuzzleHttp\Pool::GuzzleHttp\{closure}()
#14 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/EachPromise.php(73): Generator->rewind()
#15 /path/to/my/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Pool.php(74): GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise->promise()
#16 /path/to/my/project/class/crondaemon.php(5073): GuzzleHttp\Pool->promise()
#17 [internal function]: CronDaemon->DeleteWopiDocs()
#18 /path/to/my/project/tests/cron.php(46): call_user_func(Array)
#19 /path/to/my/project/tests/cron.php(51): CronDaemonTestScript::main(Array)
#20 {main}
```

It looks like the exception is being thrown on the `$client->delete` line, but I thought that was supposed to create a `Request` object but not send it yet (that's the job of the pool)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`client::get(), client::put(), client::post(), client::delete()` are abstractions for `client::request()` which in itself is an abstraction for `client::requestAsync().`You are attempting to yield a `ResponseInterface` instance.
If you are going to use `GuzzleHttp\Pool`, you will have to manually create the `Psr\http-message\Request` objects.

```
yield new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request($method, $uri, $headers_array, $body, $protocol_version);
```

Further information can be obtained by checking out [concurrent requests](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests) and  [GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/master/src/Request.php#L36)

Edit: Response to question in comments.
Ultimately, each request you want to have sent, is sent using `Client::sendAsync()`. This means that any option previously configured within the Client will remain valid while it is being used within the pool.

Comment: Is there no way to take advantage of the `$client` object which sets the `base_uri` and other defaults for me when using a Pool?

Comment: Updated response to include answer to comment.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that I have to wrap the Promise in a function for some reason:

```
foreach (array_chunk($paths, self::WOPI_SOFT_DELETE_CHUNK_SIZE) as $chunk) {
    yield function() use ($client, $files) {
        return $client->deleteAsync('/', [
            'body' => json_encode(['paths' => $files]),
        ]);
    };
}
```